# can dynamic paint be the origin of particle?

Tags: particles, dynamic-paint

i wonder if it is possible to have a particle sytem A that rains down to another object, where it would act as paint on a canvas. (so far i get it working)

But next i wonder could this canvas paint be used to be a origin of another particle system on the canvas object ?

Comment: by origin you mean the density map for an other particle system that controls where particles spawn

Comment: yes thats what i mean